# How can I make a chronometer for an HL2: EP2 Mod?

Tags: modding, timer, source-engine

I'm trying to make a chronometer for a mod I created. I looked on the web, but there are only countdown timers for TF2, nothing for HL2: EP2. In my case, it is an absolute necessity to use HL2: EP2.

The idea is: the player runs through a trigger, the chronometer starts, and at the end of the level, the time elapsed to complete it is displayed. I am using Hammer Editor.

Firstly, it is not necessary that the time is displayed on HUD. 
I want to be able to count the time elapsed between a trigger enabling it and another input stopping it.

I've taken a close look to logic_timer and to [math_counter](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Math_counter), but I don't know how to retrieve the time elapsed since the logic_timer activated the math_counter, neither how to display it on screen.

I managed to fire an output from the logic_timer each second, and that it increases the math_counter, but I am unable to retrieve the value of the math_counter. I've also taken close looks to the OutValue and OnGetValue outputs (math_counter) but nothinng is telling how to get its value...

Finally, I followed [Customizable triggered HUD-message](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Customizable_triggered_HUD_message) tutorial, and I can see it in Hammer Editor, but the Output that was added is not working. This tutorial explains how to have displayed HUD message coming from inputs instead of several game_text. When I use it on my map, nothing happens.